# Selenium website tab won't open. NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'am truying to open "Admin" from that website with Selenuim in PyCharm and everytime after login it dont want go further and give me NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper']"}
I triet time and wait commands but still it dont want to click() this Admin tab and go further

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications") 

serv_obj = Service("C:\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj, options=option)

my_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=2, ignored_exceptions=[NoSuchElementException,                                                                          ElementNotVisibleException,                                                                          ElementNotSelectableException,
Exception]
                        )

driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
driver.maximize_window()

searchlink = my_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
searchlink.send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()

time.sleep(4)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='oxd-main-menu-item-wrapper']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='User Management']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@role='menuitem']").click()
```

Comment: There is no such element there. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: trying to open "system users" table, but for that I need to go"admin" page first, than click "user managment" , than "users". Login going with no problem, but after that it dont want to do a .click() on a "admin"